# Towing AWD Subaru 2010 Outback with auto/manual transmission

Tags: towing, awd

I read the posts about towing behind an RV. My 2010 Subaru Outback had an automatic transmission, but it also has the manual shift up and down paddles on the steering wheel. Does this mean it can be towed or is it ONLY the totally manual transmission that can be towed.  I don't think I can put it in neutral, I would have to place the stick in Manual position.

Answer (score 1):

It is talking about a fully manual transmission. Even with the paddle shifters, the Outback you describe is still an automatic, just with an alternate shifting method.

Answer (score 1):

You should consult your Owner's Manual if your vehicle is capable of being flat-towed without damage.

However, being a Subaru junkie, I would suggest that the answer is *absolutely not*.   There's vital lubrication that needs to occur that is usually effected by pump pressure, which is a result of the engine running and dricing the transaxle pump.  simply flat-towing may cause thousands of dollars worth of damage.

But to be sure, check your owner's manaul.

Comment: Also: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/14835/22368.  If you are going to tow an AWD vehicle, get a trailer.